# Text Color in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

After installing python on Visual Studio Code, the text color that I have is only white and no longer displays colors when I give commands, and this is bugging me. Please help!

Comment: You mean in the editor? Colour of code?

Answer (score 2):

An article from vscode website about "Color Themes":

> 1. Open the Color Theme picker with File > Preferences > Color Theme. (Code > Preferences > Color Theme on Mac)
> 2. Use the cursor keys to preview the colors of the theme.
> 3. Select the theme you want and hit Enter.

If you don't want to use a given color schemes you can check out more information here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, I had the same problem but **I just saved my file (with extension)** and boom I was getting colour.